# Copying values from an excel table into a table in a word document

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, python-docx

I'm very new to python and i'm trying to copy values from an excel table to a word table

here's my code

```
import pandas as pd
from docx import Document
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
from pathlib import Path

base_dir = Path(__file__).parent
word_template_path = base_dir / "WordTemplate.docx"
excel_path = base_dir / "ExcelSource.xlsx"
output_dir = base_dir / "OUTPUT"

# Create output folder for the word document
output_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

# convert Excel Sheet Into Pandas Dataframe
df = pd.read_excel(excel_path, sheet_name="Feuil2")

# dataframe to dictionary
sda = df.to_dict("records")
doc = Document("WordTemplate.docx")
#get the first table in the document
Table = doc.tables[0]

for rows in Table.rows:
    for cells in rows.cells:
        Dictionary = {
            rows.cells[0]: sda["ORDER"],
            rows.cells[1]: sda["ITEM"],
            rows.cells[2]: sda["Q1"],
            rows.cells[3]: sda["Q2"],
            rows.cells[4]: sda["PRICE"],
            rows.cells[5]: sda["TVA"],
            rows.cells[6]: sda["TOTAL"],
         }
```

i tried to create a dictionary where each key is a row cell and it corresponds to record from the excel file but i'm stuck in this part where it says :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wewsos\Desktop\Folders\New folder\New folder (9)\PythonTest\fufu\ha.py", line 26, in <module>
    rows.cells[0]: sda["ORDER"],
                   ~~~^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 0):

`sda` is a list of dictionaries, not a single dictionary, you need to iterate over it.

And you don't need to iterate over the cells in `rows`, since you're indexing it with `rows.cells[0]`.

```
for rows, item in zip(Table.rows, sda):
    Dictionary = {
        rows.cells[0]: item["ORDER"],
        rows.cells[1]: item["ITEM"],
        rows.cells[2]: item["Q1"],
        rows.cells[3]: item["Q2"],
        rows.cells[4]: item["PRICE"],
        rows.cells[5]: item["TVA"],
        rows.cells[6]: item["TOTAL"],
     }
```

Comment: although it's executed successfully when i used this , the cells themselves aren't getting filled with the record entries, i tried rows.cells.text: item["ORDER"] but it didn't fill the cells with anything

Comment: You're not assigning to the cells, you're using the contents of the cells as the keys in a dictionary. I assumed there was more code in the loop that would use `Dictionary` for something.

Comment: If you want to fill in the cells, use `rows.cells[0] = item["ORDER"]`

Comment: when i used `rows.cells[0].text = item["ORDER"]` ORDER being a number it says int object is not iterable. however when i replace ORDER which is a number by ITEM which is a string it does the job, so i think i need to convert the integers in the dictionary to strings right?

Comment: Yep that was it all i needed was the str() function, thank you so much for your help